# Join two tables in one table to change the Id's by names

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Im creating an absence management web application for an enterprise. I need to list the requests when an employee chooses the period of time.

I have 3 tables about the Requests.

The principal table to list the requests on table that is the Requests, I have also RequestState table which can be Pending, Approved or Declined and the RequestType table which can be Medical Leave, Holidays etc...

Table Request :

- RequestId
- Subject
- Description
- StartDate
- EndDate
- TypeId
- StateId
- UserId

Table RequestStates

- StateId (ForeignKey TableRequest)
- Name (Pending,Approved.. etc)

Table RequestType

- TypeId (ForeignKey TableRequest)
- Name (Medical Leave, Holidays ...)

Im working with asp.net mvc and angularJs. With EntityFramework I am making queries to list with angularJS.

So i want to list in a html table The request table list that I will show you in an image with the TypeId and StateId. But i want to show the name of TypeID and StateId instead of the number.

In my EntityFramework query what I need to do? A join?

This is the code to get all PendingRequests, it will return a json with the keys that are on table Requests. But I want to change or use something in the query to get the name of the other tables (RequestState and RequestType) instead of the Ids.

```
 public JsonResult GetAllPendingRequests()
    {
        var data = "";
        using (CiberbitHolidayMgmt bd = new CiberbitHolidayMgmt())
        {           
            bd.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var pendingRequests = bd.Requests.Where(a => a.StateId == 1);

            data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pendingRequests, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    });
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = data, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Code about ng repeat and JavaScript where i have the http request

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat =" a in getPendingRequests">
          <td>{{a.TypeId}}</td>
          <td>{{a.StartDate}} - {{a.EndDate}}</td>
          <td>{{a.Requested}} days</td>
          <td>{{a.StateId}}</td>
          <td><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Request")"><i class="fas fa-info-circle "></i></a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>


 function getAllPendingRequests() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Request/GetAllPendingRequests',
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            data.data = JSON.parse(data.data);
            $scope.getAllPendingRequests = data.data;

            console.log($scope.getAllPendingRequests);

        }, function (data) {
            alert("error");
        });
    }
```

[Html Table with requests list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGmPg.png)
[EntityFramework model with the tables][2]

Basically i want to display the names and not the Ids on the html table about the State and Type Request and I think I need a EntityFramework query with joins. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the image with the query that I did!

I select from different tables, match the id's and created a object!

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGmPg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not question of html or angularjs.

You need to do query with EntityFramework and return proper data (Names of the RequestState and RequestType instead of the Ids).

First you need to establish proper Entity mappings:

In the `Request` table's entity mapping add the virtual properties for the RequestState and RequestType like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<RequestState> RequestStates { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<RequestType> RequestTypes { get; set; }
```

Then in the RequestState and RequestType class add the virtual property of the `Request` class like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Request> Categories { get; set; }
```

Now you should be able to do the query like this:

```
var allRequests = db.Request.Where(r => r.TypeId == reqTypeId)
                  .SelectMany(r => r.Request);
```

Where in the result, for each object in `allRequests` you will get the properties like `r.RequestStates.Name` and `r.RequestTypes.Name`

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer! I tried that but i had a problem. When i try to make the query at the end SelectMany(r => r.Request) the "Request doesnt appear", in my case is Requests. The options that i have available doest appear Requests and i did all you said :)

Comment: @HélderBarreto instead of `.SelectMany(r => r.Request);` you can also do ToList() on the query. It would either return an empty list if no data is found or return a list with data.

Comment: I dont know if im doing something wrong but the final return of my data the RequestStates and RequestType are null, how can i get access to the name? On Entity Maping i did what you refered

Comment: It could be the query. Can you change the query and try something like this: `var requests = db.Requests.Include(z => z.RequestStates).ToList();` and see if in the list you have the data of the RequestStates too? Then you can find out why RequestStates  or RequestTypes are null.

Comment: I used in the query the RequestState from the Collection that i created. I have this on my Request table's entity mapping --> 2 publics ICollection that you said to create and also 2 public virtual RequestStates and RequestsTypes. I used the include in the query and i had an error like 
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'CiberbitHolidaysModel.Requests' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'RequestState'.

Comment: If you agree we can use another method to comunicate and to understand better my problem, for example skype i can send images :)

Comment: We can talk on skype. add me as rahat651. I am away at the moment. Will reply later and set a time to talk.